# Get the Beginning Position Of a field

Tags: java

Hi Guys I am writing a code that reads a text file in this format:

```
City             |First Name| Second Name|Last Name|
```

The output I currently have is :

```
Column 1 is 17--------City
Column 2 is 10--------First Name
Column 3 is 12--------Second Name
Column 4 is 9---------Last Name
```

I need the Begin Position Also Of each Field in the Text File for example:

```
Column 1 is 17--------City : Position 1
Column 2 is 10--------First Name: Position 18
Column 3 is 12--------Second Name: Position 31
Column 4 is 9---------Last Name: Position 44
```

Here Is the Code I currently Have. Is there a way to achieve This?

```
 package stanley.column.reader;

 import java.io.*;

 public class StanleyColumnReader {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Developed By Stanley Mungai");       
        File f = new File("C:/File/");
        if (!f.exists()) {
            f.createNewFile();
        } else {
            f.delete();
        }
        String [] files = f.list();
        for (int j = 0; j < files.length; j++){
            FileInputStream fs = new FileInputStream("C:/File/" + files[j]);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fs));
            String result = "_result";
            BufferedWriter is = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/File/" + files[j] + result + ".txt"));
            for (int i = 0; i < 0; i++) {
                br.readLine();
            }

            String line = br.readLine();
            String[] split = line.split("|");
            for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
                int k = i + 1;
                System.out.println("Calculating the size of field " + k );
                is.write("Column " + k + " is " + split[i].length());
                is.flush();
                is.newLine();
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Success");
        System.out.println("Output Saved to C:/File");
    }
}
```

Comment: just to throw this in: if you're going to read character separated files it's easier to use a csv-library like [http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do that with a bit more advanced regexp group matching and get the group start index. But might be overkill and too advanced considering the question.

But a quick simple way in your case that might work is to just use `indexOf` on the line.
That is change your output to include:

```
" Position "+(line.indexOf(split[i])+1)
```

As long as a last name, first name and city aren't repeated on the same line...

You hardly need to flush on each line by the way, I suggest to move it outside the loop.

The regexp solution:

```
//first declare the pattern once in the class
static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\s*(.*?)\\s*\\|");
...
//instead of the split loop:
String line = "City             |First Name| Second Name|Last Name| Foo |Bar |"; //br.readLine();
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
int column = 1;
while (matcher.find(column == 1 ? 0 : matcher.end())) {
    String match = matcher.group(1);
    System.out.println("Column " + column + " is " + match.length() + "---" + match + ": Position " + (matcher.start() + 1));
    column++;
}
```

Possibly, depending on the exact position you want, you might want to change `(matcher.start()+1)` to `(matcher.start(1)+1)`

Comment: `" Position "+(line.indexOf(split[i])+1)`  - offset by 1

Comment: Why offset 1? I don't see a definition for Position so I  wouldn't know though but assuming it starts at index 0, if first position is 1 then add 1 yes.

Comment: Java strings start with index 0. OP said the  position for Column 1 is 1. The other thing is if any two columns have the same string value, it is going to return the position of 1st match.

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, jsut that we don't know form the question. Column index is doing +1, but index in the line (position) is not defined from what I can see? Update: Well from the examples given City is at 1, I see what you mean.

Comment: Thanx guys for the contribution, See, the Data Might be repeated in the next column as the file is very big. I need the Character begining Position of each field without the repetition as the " Position "+(line.indexOf(split[i])+1)   Method would return the same position if the Field id repeated.

Comment: OK I'll update the answer with a regexp solution instead then.

Comment: My File does Not have For Fields, it has over 400 Fields and the Files are different. Each with  a different Number of fields. This regex code Above oNly Displays information for the First Four Columns. How can we display Information for all the Cloumns?

Comment: Will have to keep matching in a loop until not matching anymore for that line, can simplify the regexp as well actually. I can update the code later to reflect this when I have more time

Comment: This Code above does not take into consideration the fields that may be blank.

Comment: Can we take care of the fields that Are Blank To? e.g. |          |

Comment: Yes a trivial change, just change the capture from *one or more* `(.+?)` to *zero or more* `(.*?)`

Comment: @Mattias: Why does 'match.length()' return 0 for the length of fields that are blank. I want the Field Value even if the Field is blank.

Comment: Well `match.length()` is the length of the field, a blank field is 0 length of course. Where you thinking about the position?

Comment: @Mattias The Position is Ok Am talking about where Between Two Pipes there is Nothing Written on it But there is space for length. Please See the example I posted at the End of this question:

Comment: Please define "consider". Do you want to include the spaces in the length you mean? I explicitly removed those from the length and match in my answer. Just change the regexp to include them in the capture if you want them in there. Meaning, move (or add if you want two capturing groups, one with the spaces and one without) the `(`an `)` to include the whitespace characters. Meaning move first to the start of the regexp and the last jsut before the pipe `\\|` in the regxp.

Answer (score 2):

IS this an `assignment`? Please tag it properly.

You haven't said whether the delimiters are `"|"` in the data too but seeing your code, I am assuming it is.

What I don't understand is how the position you mentioned for Column 3 is 31 and column 4 is 44? Column 3 should be 10+17+1 =28 and column 4 should be 10+17+12+1=40. If I am getting it wrong, you need to post your original data too.

```
String[] split = line.split("|");
int pos=1; //initial position
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Calculating the size of field " + (i+1));
    is.write("Column " + (i+1) + " is " + pos+" : Position "+pos);
    pos=pos+split[i].length+1; //starting position for next column data
    is.flush();
    is.newLine();
}
```

Or you could find position by using `indexOf` method : `line.indexOf(split[i])+1`

Comment: The position of the first field will be 1 the second will be the field length of the first + 1, The third will be the first field length + the second field length +2 because of the | Delimeters.

Comment: I see, I added `+1` to the position. Next time, please post original data to avoid confusion.

Comment: Also your position numbering for Column 2 is 18 which is wrong. Because you should add 1 for for delimiter and it will be 19.

Comment: You have got me all wrong. The position of the first field will be 1 - Good. the second will be the field length of the first + 1 - wrong because your 2nd column starts after delimiter so it is length of 1st + 1 for delimiter + 1 = 19 and your 3rd starting position will be: length of 1st + 1st delimiter  +length of 2nd +2nd delimiter + 1 = 30.

Comment: I think I did not explain Myself Properly. This is because the code Above Displays The field number. I need the Exact Character Position.

Comment: Please post your original data as you make no sense to me. Does each column start with the delimiter or after the delimiter? If it starts after the delimiter, your 1st comment is wrong and your position numbers are wrong. Check for 2nd column position number: First column data length + delimiter length + 1 = 17 + 1 + 1 = 19! Note: Your 1st column starts with 1 where there is no delimiter!! and your 2nd column starts at 18? when 1st column has length of 17? You make no sense

Comment: As far as i can see, this should be correct starting psotions for each columns: 1st column: position 1, 2nd column: position (17+1 delimiter +1)=19, 3rd column: position (17 + 1 delimiter + 10 + 1 delimtier + 1)=30, 4th column : position (17 + 1 delimiter + 10 + 1 delimiter + 12 + 1 delimiter + 1)=43

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you need. Maybe you can use the indexOf method. This brings you the first coincidence. After finding this, change the pipe for something different and call indexOf pipe in the next iteration again.

```
String line = br.readLine();
for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
        System.out.println("Calculating the position " + line.indexOf("|") );
        line[line.indexOf("|")] = ",";
}
```

Comment: I like Pulsar answer because is concise, but like he mentioned be sure that you don't have people with the same second and last name. That's something common in Mexico, Mr. Pacho Lopez Lopez :p If you opt for my solution you will need to have two different separators that will never appear in the String.

Comment: The fields are repeated and so the method would not be appropriate